# button_to without submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

**Can I have a button in side the form, but do not have the `type=submit`?**

I am doing something special. I have a form,

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

and this form will be rendered based on a value in a session.

In side the form, I have `f.submit` already and I want to have another button, cancel button, to invoke a method from controller to change the session value if user want to cancel the input.

But if I use `button_to`, the type of the button will be "submit", when I click on the button, it will submit the whole form. If some of the value are not valid, it will complain. It does not work as the "cancel" button that I expected.

So can I have a button that does not submit the form?

I tried  to use submit_tag, but the buttom dosn`t work for me...

```
<%= submit_tag 'Cancel Edit', :type => 'button', :controller => 'my_account', :action=>'cancel_edit' %>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`button_to` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) actually generates a whole form:

> Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of `options`.

So that's definitely not what you want. I think you just want to generate a simple `<input type="button">` element in your HTML. However, there is no `button_tag` in [`FormTagHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) but there is a [`submit_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) that you can hand a `:type` option to and that will:

> Any other key creates standard HTML options for the tag.

So try this:

```
submit_tag 'Pancakes', :type => 'button'
```

where "Pancakes" would be your real label.

Comment: @shrimpy: Hook some JavaScript.

Comment: There is a .button method for forms.

Comment: a `link_to` would also do the job

Answer (score 31):

Try the following:

```
<%= button_tag "Cancel", :type => 'button', :class => "subBtn", :onclick => "location.href = '#{list_admin_users_admin_index_path()}'" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper similar to `f.submit`:

`<%= f.button 'Save' %>`

[Documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/button)